# Dashboard can not be deleted because "This dashboard is mapped in users."

Tags: dashboard

When I delete a dashboard. It did show me the message as the image below
[image]

How can I delete this dashboard ? I have gone to Google but nothing is found.

Comment: Please check with the Community administrator who can only map them for you to be visible in the community.

Comment: Thanks @ShirishaPathuri, I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you were able to delete the dashboard once you reach out to the Community administrator who can only map the dashaboards for the user to make them visible.

Thank you!